# The sixth frame is a repeat of the fifth frame

Tags: framerate

I'm analysing a  dashcam video clip (avi format) frame by frame. According to media information when I open this video file, the frame rate is 30 fps. However I noticed that every sixth frame is actually a repeat of the fifth frame, like as if it is 25 fps. What the reason why and how I can I get rid of the duplicate frames? Was it actually 25 fps but saved as 30 fps? Any tips? Thanks.

Michael

Comment: Do you know the brand and model of the camera? It's possible that the hardware only films at 25 fps, but the software repeats frames to bump it to 30. Also, what software are you examining it in?

Comment: This can be done with ffmpeg and select filter.

Comment: [I had same situation in youtube:](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23155/why-this-youtube-videos-repeat-a-frame-every-5-or-6-frames)